# "Main actor-isolated property can not be mutated from a non-isolated context" in Swift Unit Testing

Tags: swift, unit-testing

My "main app model" inspired from the Donut Truck example looks like this,

```swift
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
public class AcmeModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var events: [Event] = []

    /**
        Only serves upcoming events in ascending order
     */
    func upcoming() -> [Event] {
        return
            events
                .filter { $0.date >= Date() }
                .sorted{ $0.date > $1.date }
    }

}
```

The intention should be obvious. I now want to test that `upcoming()` indeed returns only the Events that are in the future, and in in ascending order.

I started with…

```swift
import XCTest
@testable import acme

final class acmeModelTests: XCTestCase {

    func testUpcomingFiltersFutureAndOrdersNextUp() async {
        let candidate = await AcmeModel()
        candidate.events = [] // [1] comp error, see text

        //throw XCTSkip()
        //XCTAssert…

    }

}
```

The line [1] with `candidate.events = []` gives the error »Main actor-isolated property 'events' can not be mutated from a non-isolated context«. I somehow understand what that means, it's encapsulated and all, but how can I react for Unit testing?
I might revert to constructor-injection but this would only be my best-guess and maybe there's a better fitting solution for this.

For the sake of completeness, the code that actually uses this looks like,

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model: AcmeModel

    var body: some View {
    // …
    }.onAppear {
            Task {
                if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                    do {
                        model.events =
                            try await eventRepository.allEventsOf(
                                aUser: UserId(currentUser.uid))
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, why is your test function declared as `async`? And secondly if it must be can't you require it to run on the main thread as well using `@MainActor`?

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson see my own answer, we had a small race condition :)

Answer (score 1):

I found it right after reviewing, credits to https://www.avanderlee.com/concurrency/unit-testing-async-await/#unit-testing-ui-logic-using-mainactor. [edit: and @Joakim Danielson who answered it in a comment as well]

I have to also add `@MainActor` to the test, so it finally looks like this (in case it might be helpful I've added the whole thing):

```swift
import XCTest
@testable import acme

@MainActor
final class acmeModelTests: XCTestCase {

    func testUpcomingFiltersFutureAndOrdersNextUp() {

        let next = Event.preview(withDate: Event.inThreeWeeksAt730())
        let eventAfterNext = Event.preview(withDate: Event.inAboutFourWeeks())
        let past = Event.preview(withDate: Event.aboutYesterday())

        let candidate = AcmeModel()
        candidate.events = [
            eventAfterNext,
            past,
            next
        ]

        XCTAssertEqual(candidate.upcoming(), [next, eventAfterNext])

    }

}
```